# Offline map script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm making a website with a ground plan on it. First I used google maps for the functions it has, but my boss told me that the site will also run on computers with no internet access.

Then I used jquery geo but it misses some stuff that I need (like markers). And it's a alpha version.

The thing I need is a script that I can download that shows my own map tiles and has markers where I can click on. The map needs to pan and zoom.

Does someone knows a library that does it?

Comment: Either you write the stuff you're missing or tell your boss that the application needs internet access. You can't both have the cake and eat it. :-)

Comment: I'm not so good with javascript to write the missing stuff and internet access is no option. The customers won't allow internet access to the webserver.

Comment: Try using [**OpenLayers**](http://openlayers.org/). They claim "OpenLayers is a pure JavaScript library for displaying map data in most modern web browsers, with no server-side dependencies" so it should run by loading from disk, or worst case, from a local HTTP server.